# Why is Typescript ignoring my check for 'undefined'?

Tags: typescript

Even when I check if my Object is not `undefined` TS is complaining.

A sample of my code:

```
if (state.get(action.layer.name) != undefined) {
   return state.get(action.layer.name).data.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.item.id);
}
```

TS says:

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
```

What Im doing wrong?

Comment: How's it supposed to know (for that matter, how do _you_ know) that's returned the same value you checked? Assign the result to a variable, then narrow _that_.

Comment: You also may need to use "!==" instead of "!=".
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_inequality

Comment: Please provide a [mre] suitable that others can paste into a standalone IDE to demonstrate your issue for themselves.  Right now `state` and `action` are not defined or declared.

Answer (score 0):

Even if whatever is returned from `state.get(action.layer.name)` is not undefined, it does not guarantee that what is returned has a `data` property so that `Object.data` would be undefined.

Perhaps you can try checking

```
if (state.get(action.layer.name).data !== undefined) {
   return state.get(action.layer.name).data.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.item.id);
}
```

Comment: That is indeed _slightly_ better. But as implied by @jonrsharpe's comment, we do not even know if the 2 calls to `state.get()` give the same result (and calling them with the same argument is not a guarantee of such).